# Передача параметра конструктора в Spring

Tags: spring, java

Можно ли в Spring при инициализации бина передать параметр конструктора, чтобы вызывался конструктор не по умолчанию?

Например: мой бин это `ArrayList` и я хочу при его создании указать размер, то есть Spring-у, чтобы корректно создать мой бин нужно было бы вызвать конструктор `ArrayList(int size)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<bean class="java.util.ArrayList">
   <constructor-arg type="int"><value>10</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```